# Retry for Spring Cloud Kubernetes application

Tags: spring, kubernetes, cloud

I am currently implementing application with Spring Cloud (2022.0.3) deployed in Kubernetes cluster. Service discovery is using Kubernetes API server using spring cloud discovery client with spring cloud load balancer for load balancing. No ribbon or other discovery mechanism. Looking for options for retrying API calls. The options are using spring load balancer client(https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#rest-template-loadbalancer-client) and using Resilience4J. Not managed to get it work using load balancer client. The advantage of resilience4j is it can be used with Spring Actuator to monitor the number of retries and other metrics and information. But the query is if an API call fails and resilience4j retries, is the client side list of POD IPs refreshed by discoveryclient? A particular POD not responding may be temporary due to load or may be detected by Kubernetes from failed liveness. Just to want to ensure the use of Resilience4j actually help remove the failed PODs from discovery client based on number of failure and all future calls are not routed to the failed PODs.